# Vi group independent commands in normal mode

Tags: vim, operators, vi

I want to execute a set of independent(by this I mean which don't take each other as arguments) commands n times in vi (vim to be more precise).
How can I group the commands?
An example would be (I know it's a stupid command but I just want to illustrate my point):

`80jl`

How can I make vim execute both `j` and `l` commands 80 times?
Is there a composition operator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can record those commands using `q` and execute them using `@`, so:

```
qajlq
```

saves in register `a` the two movements, and:

```
80@a
```

execute 80 times the content of register `a`.